# Positioning popup window in middle of the screen without JavaScript

Tags: css, popupwindow

I have following HTML and CSS, now I would like to position my popup window in middle of screen in any browser window size. Is this possible without JavaScript?

CSS:

```
.floating-window {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
height: 200px;  
    cursor: default;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #888;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='floating-window box'></div>
```

Comment: Pop-up windows on websites are so 1990s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With percentages, you can set your box such that half of it is on the left side.  So

```
width: 30%;
left: 45%; /* 50% (center) - 15% (half of 30) */
```

You could also use px but then you'll be limited to an absolute container width.  Have you searched around?  I know there are some articles explaining this method more extensively than I have.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible, but how are you going to make it go away?

That's going to need JavaScript...

Comment: That is true, but if JavaScript is not needed, why use it instead of CSS ?

Comment: People often use JavaScript to do things they could do in CSS.  Beats me.